# Struct doesn't implement interface even if it has the same functions

Tags: go

I don't know what is the reason of following compilation error. I will  appreciate any help.

```
./router.go:190: cannot use listener (type webhooklistener.MyListener) as type webhook.Listener in field value:
    webhooklistener.MyListener does not implement webhook.Listener (missing webhook.handle method)
        have webhooklistener.handle()
        want webhook.handle()
```

Client:

```
package webhook

type Listener interface {
    handle()
}

type Client struct {
    Listener Listener
}
```

Listener:

```
package webhooklistener

type MyListener struct {
}

func (ll MyListener) handle() {

}
```

Router:

```
listener := webhooklistener.MyListener{}
client := webhook.Client{listener} // COMPILATION ERROR
```

Comment: Try capitalizing the `handle()` method, it's probably not being exported for external use.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`webhook.Listener`'s only method is unexported, so only identifiers in that package can implement it. If you want types in other packages to be able to implement it, you need to make it exported:

```
type Listener interface {
    Handle()
}
```